# Spark: Proper way to remove the last element of an RDD[String]

Tags: scala, performance, apache-spark

I am trying to remove the last element of an RDD[String].

So far I'm doing this:

```
val n: Long = rdd.count()
val startIndex: Long = n - 1

val lastElem = rdd.zipWithIndex()
  .filter{ case (_, index) => index >= startIndex }
  .keys
  .collect()

val newRdd = rdd.filter(x => !x.equalsIgnoreCase(lastElem(0))).cache()
```

That is, taking the last element of the rdd, and filter it to get all the elements less the last one.

This is working well, but is there a better way to do it?

Comment: try this `rdd.collect.dropRight(1)` to remove last element from `RDD[String]`

Comment: Hi, @Yogesh    That expression is for Array[String]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is `init` function in scala *which gives you all the elements except the last one in a collection*. You can utilize that one

```
val newRdd = sc.parallelize(rdd.collect().toList.init)
```

this should give you *new rdd by removing the last element* and is better than your approach as collect is used only once.

**And rdd is distributed and there is no way to tell which one is the last string without collecting it to one node.**

Here *I have collected it to the driver node*. *You can use another technique to collect to one executor* and use `init` function

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the order is well defined (there are no wide transformations upstream and the input source guarantees well defined order of elements) your current solution is as good as it gets.

Especially you should avoid not scalable  and overall useless (if order of values in RDD is not well defined, order value in the `collected` `Array` is not well defined as well.) `collect`.

Before using please be sure to understand the limitation. [Quoting the docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD):

> Note that some RDDs, such as those returned by groupBy(), do not guarantee order of elements in a partition. The unique ID assigned to each element is therefore not guaranteed, and may even change if the RDD is reevaluated. If a fixed ordering is required to guarantee the same index assignments, you should sort the RDD with sortByKey() or save it to a file.