# Scala - How to select the last element from an RDD?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

First I had a `salesList: List[Sale]` and in order to get an ID of the last Sale in the List I've used `lastOption`:

```
val lastSaleId: Option[Any] = salesList.lastOption.map(_.saleId)
```

But now I've modified a method with `List[Sale]` to work with `salesListRdd: List[RDD[Sale]]`. So  I've changed the way I'm getting an ID of the last Sale:

```
  val lastSaleId: Option[Any] = SparkContext
    .union(salesListRdd)
    .collect().toList
    .lastOption.map(_.saleId)
```

I'm not sure that it is the best way to go. Because here I'm still collecting RDD to a List which brings it to the driver node and it may cause the driver to run out of memory.

Is there a way to get an ID of the last Sale from an RDD preserving the initial order of records? Not any kind of sorting but the way the Sale objects were originally stored in the List?

Comment: we have takeRight(1)? on RDD right?

Comment: @RamanMishra as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50420301/spark-proper-way-to-remove-the-last-element-of-an-rddstring) `rdd is distributed and there is no way to tell which one is the last string without collecting it to one node`

Answer (score 3):

There at least two efficient solutions. You can either use `top` with `zipWithIndex`:

```
def lastValue[T](rdd: RDD[T]): Option[T] = {
  rdd.zipWithUniqueId.map(_.swap).top(1)(Ordering[Long].on(_._1)).headOption.map(_._2)
}
```

or `top` with custom key:

```
 def lastValue[T](rdd: RDD[T]): Option[T] = {
   rdd.mapPartitionsWithIndex(
     (i, iter) => iter.zipWithIndex.map {  case (x, j) => ((i, j), x) }
   ).top(1)(Ordering[(Int, Long)].on(_._1)).headOption.map(_._2)
 }
```

The former one requires additional action for `zipWithIndex` while the latter one doesn't.

Before using please be sure to understand the limitation. [Quoting the docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD):

> Note that some RDDs, such as those returned by groupBy(), do not guarantee order of elements in a partition. The unique ID assigned to each element is therefore not guaranteed, and may even change if the RDD is reevaluated. If a fixed ordering is required to guarantee the same index assignments, you should sort the RDD with sortByKey() or save it to a file.

In particular, depending on the exact input, `Union` might not preserve the input order at all.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `zipWithIndex` and sort `descending` by it, so that the last record will be on the top, then take(1):

```
salesListRdd
    .zipWithIndex()
    .map({ case (x, y) => (y, x) })
    .sortByKey(ascending = false)
    .map({ case (x, y) => y })
    .take(1)
```

Solution is taken from here: http://www.swi.com/spark-rdd-getting-bottom-records/
However, it is highly inefficient, since It does lots of partition shuffling.